# What's the word when someone tries to change the meaning of a statement by using different definitions for specific words?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

For example the second amendment in the American constitution "the right of the people to keep and bear Arms" and someone argues that arms here means limbs when it clearly means guns. I remember a word similar to overstretch or overreach was used in that case.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143011/discussion-on-question-by-stefan-whats-the-word-when-someone-tries-to-change-th); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 11):

This is an informal fallacy called **equivocation** ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivocation), [RationalWiki](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Equivocation)). The latter defines it as

> a logical fallacy that relies on implicitly alternating between the different meanings a single word can have in different contexts.

[Texas State University Department of Philosophy](https://www.txst.edu/philosophy/resources/fallacy-definitions/Equivocation.html) has a page on equivocation, which says

> The fallacy of equivocation occurs when a key term or phrase in an argument is used in an ambiguous way, with one meaning in one portion of the argument and then another meaning in another portion of the argument

One common example mentioned in RationalWiki is when creationists argue that the theory evolution isn't true because it's only a theory. In science, a theory is (according to a quote in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory)) "a well-substantiated explanation of some aspect of the natural world, based on a body of facts that have been repeatedly confirmed through observation and experiment" but one of the dictionary definitions of theory is "an unproved assumption" ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/theory)). So the theory of evolution is an unproved assumption. This is an example of equivocation.

Texas State gives as an example:

> The laws imply lawgivers. There are laws in nature. Therefore there must be a cosmic lawgiver.

Here the concept of a law of nature is confused with a law in the legal system.

Comment: Reminder: The comments here are *not* the place to discuss the theory of evolution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of the **Logical Fallacy of Re-Definition**, where an original statement of fact is disputed by re-defining the terms of reference.

[Logical Fallacy : Redefinition](https://www.fallacyfiles.org/redefine.html)

[Redefinition Fallacy](https://www.seekfind.net/Redefinition_Fallacy.html#.Y_JHpHbP200)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the word "wrest"--especially if it were done intentionally.  A similar word would be "twist" or "distort."

For example:

"He *wrested* the meaning of the statement, turning it into something altogether different than originally intended."

Apple's Dictionary (from Oxford Dictionaries) claims this usage is archaic, but its usage of "distort" is not a perfect replacement.  "Wrest" implies intent; "distort" is more neutral, and could as easily include an accidental misusage or misunderstanding of something.

Here is the dictionary entry.

> **wrest** | rest | 
> **verb** [with object] 
> forcibly pull (something) from a person's grasp: *Leila tried to wrest her arm from
> his hold.*
>
> - take (something, especially power or control) from someone or something else after considerable effort or difficulty: *they wanted
>   to allow people to wrest control of their lives from impersonal
>   bureaucracies.*
> - **archaic** distort the meaning or interpretation of (something) to suit one's own interests or views: *you appear convinced of my guilt,
>   and wrest every reply I have made.*
>
> **noun archaic** a key for tuning a harp or piano.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs I added the dictionary entry to my answer.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs. Please tell me how to credit it and I will.  It comes, copy/pasted, from my "Dictionary.app" on my MacBook--which has no attestation as to its source.

Comment: @HippoSawrUs There's no such thing as a hyperlink on this site to an app on my computer.  That is why I did not originally even include the definition--shall I just remove it?

Comment: @HippoSawrUs. I cannot link to an app on my computer.  Why would that be possible?  It's not online.

Comment: BTW, if your version is older than 10.7, it will not include their British dictionary, which may explain why the entry you found was tagged as archaic and the one from OL&G is not.